# Send emails using gmail after Oauth 2.0 in MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-oauth, sendmail

I want to send email over google/gmail from my mvc application after oauth.

I am using mvc 4. My application will ask for authorize this app for oauth.
Then I want to send email to other user from the application.

If you help me through code and step to do, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Postal](http://aboutcode.net/postal/) which is very handy and easy to use ,to send emails

Controller

```
dynamic email = new Email("Email");
email.To = UserName;
email.FirstName = FName;
email.LastName = LName;
email.Send();
```

Then in your View Email

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

To: @ViewBag.To
From: Example lolcats@website.com
Subject: blah blah

Hello @ViewBag.FirstName,

Your Text.........
This is auto generated email please do not reply.
```

**Edited**

Please add your smtp credentials in web.config

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="example@gmail.com">
    <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" enableSsl="true" userName="example@gmail.com" password="1234567" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

This is very simple. Just give a try 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi. I have installed "Install-Package Postal.Mvc4". Then I have put your code. On line "email.Send();" I am getting error : "Email view not found for Email. Locations searched:
~/Views/Emails/Email.aspx
~/Views/Emails/Email.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Email.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Email.ascx
~/Views/Emails/Email.cshtml
~/Views/Emails/Email.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Email.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Email.vbhtml"

Comment: You have not added your View . Please add the View Named 'Email' inside your views folder. And add the view code which is in my answer

Comment: Yes added. Now got "SMTP is not specified." We are moving side track. I want to send emails after oauth over SMTP and don't want to open SMTP using credentials.

Comment: Edited the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

I have made lots of work out. and Finally.... I have resolved my problem.

In C#, there is no any direct SMTP and Oauth lib. So you need to work manually.

Make Oauth2 access using api and get access "offline".

Then Refer this link [SMTP and Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195508/smtp-and-oauth-2)