# Sending mail using MailKit with Gmail OAuth

Tags: c#, email, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to create an application that will send emails to customers when they make a purchase. We have our own GMail account which I will be using to send the emails from.

I have set up my application and created credentials in the Google API Console. I found [this question](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/606) on MailKit's GitHub which looked like it'd be an easy enough approach but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here's my code:

```
var secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = [CLIENTID]
    ClientSecret = [SECRET]
};

var googleCredentials = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom }, email, CancellationToken.None);
await googleCredentials.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(googleCredentials.UserId, googleCredentials.Token.AccessToken);
    client.Authenticate(credentials);

    await client.SendAsync(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

The call to `Authenticate` gives the following error:

> MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException :
>   AuthenticationInvalidCredentials: 5.7.8 Username and Password not
>   accepted. Learn more at
>   5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials m3-v6sm3447324wrs.39 - gsmtp

The Google support page in the exception basically just says either use two-step verification + app passwords or enable less secure apps. I don't want either of these. Why is it so difficult to do this in .NET? I have done this with node before and it was incredibly simple:

```
var smtp = mailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: process.env.EMAIL,
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        refreshToken: process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN
    }
});
```

Please not that I have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24204968/5392786) but I don't really understand how I go about getting an X509 certificate that is trusted by Google. There's nothing related to this on Google's documentation as far as I can see.

Answer (score 14):

The solution was to authenticate with `SaslMechanismOAuth2` instead of `NetworkCredential`. I now have the following, which works:

```
var secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GMailClientId"),
    ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GMailClientSecret")
};

var googleCredentials = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, new[] { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom }, email, CancellationToken.None);
if (googleCredentials.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
{
    await googleCredentials.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

    var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(googleCredentials.UserId, googleCredentials.Token.AccessToken);
    client.Authenticate(oauth2);

    await client.SendAsync(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Comment: Working, great job!

Comment: For anyone trying to use this later - this is the 3-legged flow involving a user authenticating in a browser, not the service account flow.

Comment: Looking for a service account flow.

Answer (score 5):

Send email in Gmail Mailkit via Refresh Token

```
    // https://console.developers.google.com
var secrets = new ClientSecrets
{
    ClientId = "",
    ClientSecret = ""
};
// Generating a refresh token - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc
var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = "YourRefreshToken" };
var googleCredentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = secrets
    }), username, token);

emailClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);   
await googleCredentials.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(googleCredentials.UserId, googleCredentials.Token.AccessToken);
emailClient.Authenticate(oauth2);

await emailClient.SendAsync(message); // MimeMessage
emailClient.Disconnect(true);
```