# Send an email without having to enable less secure apps in google

Tags: c#, smtp, google-signin

I made an e-mailer in C#, but you have to enable less secure apps in google. Is there a way around this? If not, how do other apps send e-mails securely without being classified as a less-secure app?

```
private void SendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       try {
           SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

           mail.From = new MailAddress(myUsername);
           mail.To.Add(RecipientEmailBox.Text);
           mail.Subject = SubjectField.Text;
           mail.Body = MessageField.Text;

           SmtpServer.Port = 587;
           SmtpServer.Credentials = new 
           System.Net.NetworkCredential(myUsername, Login.password);
           SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

           SmtpServer.Send(mail);
           MessageBox.Show("Message Sent!");

       } catch (Exception ex) {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
       }
}
```

I tried researching ways to get around this, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: You could use a different SMTP server, for example, Yahoo. They may not require that step.

Comment: Can you advise where you see that you need to enable "less secure apps"?

Comment: @John there is a google setting that allows less secure apps to authenticate with your email. If I don't allow this, I get an error.

Comment: It looks like you can sign in with OAuth and use it for SMTP. See [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol#smtp_protocol_exchange). I'm not sure how this works from C#, however.

Comment: @John I can't figure out how to sign in with OAuth in C# either...

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195508/smtp-and-oauth-2) will help, although it does require using MailKit.

Comment: @John I have been trying for hours, and I have no idea how to implement that stuff, even with mailkit.

Comment: Oh, awesome. You should add an answer here on how you did it. I'm sure it will be useful to someone in future! :) Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but it's not really something I've done.

Comment: @John I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is [answer](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/html/object_oauth.htm) for question.

You can use the Google OAuth API with C#. For how to do, read the guide.

Answer (score 2):

You can no longer configure your Google account to allow connections from less secure apps, since Google [disabled that option](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) starting May 30 2022.
You have to generate an application password for your Google account.

First go to https://myaccount.google.com/security and enable 2 step verification. Once you've done that, go to 'app passwords' and generate an application password for **the mail app** to use on a **windows computer**. It will display you new app password on a yellow box, use it as your `Login.password`