# Alternative to Basic Authentication to send email from c# windows service

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, smtpclient, exchange-basicauth

- I have a C# windows service from where I send emails using SmtpClient
  and Basic Authentication.
- But as Microsoft is depreciating Basic
  Authentication as [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-september-2021-update/ba-p/2772210),
  I want to know how I can send email from my windows service using
  OAuth or any other method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely this is documented somewhere by Microsoft?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SMTP and OAuth 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195508/smtp-and-oauth-2)

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar evidently no

Comment: @Cleptus this question is specifically regarding Microsoft Exchange